# chat app with socket.io and node.js only works in my localhost...

Tags: node.js, sockets, networking, socket.io

I ve made a simple chat app using socket io and node,js and it is perfectly working in my localhost:3000 but i have no idea how to make this app accessed from other computer using other networks. Can somebody give help me please?

[This is my index html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEzqk.png)

[And this is my server js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HY30M.png)

Comment: Do you have any console errors or network errors?  Maybe it can't find socket.io.js?

Comment: I can't see any code for client side, how do you connect to server? Also put the code here not a link to the image just text and try to format it so it's easy to read.